# 70s or early 80s cartoon about some tiny humanoids on flying pirate ships

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

For years I've been trying to identify a cartoon I remember I saw as a child around 1980. A long time ago and my memory is failing me, but it was about some tiny humanoids on flying pirate ships. I saw another post here talking about a series called The Bobobobs which could have been it if it wasn't for the fact that it aired in 1988 ...

Could there be earlier versions of it? Anyone know of a similar one?

Or was I in fact a 20 years old stoner believing I was 10? :)

I only remember one thing clearly and that is that these tiny ships flew into a boy's bedroom at night and kidnapped him, or something like that :) I can't tell if it was European or Japanese style.